# How can I check if all extension are working properly?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, testing

To install a special extension I had to lower my PHP version. I don't know if this can cause trouble for my other extensions, is there a fast way to check all extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Except if you live in a parallel universe where all the extensions are shipped with unit tests. Now you have to test everything manually.

Besides that: Downgrading your PHP version is a terrible idea, especially if it's a version that doesn't get security support anymore (currently that's everything up to 5.4). I'd rather ditch the "special extension", its quality can't be that good if it's not working with a current 5.x version.

If you really can't do without it, patch it to make it compatible.

Comment: Yep, this is one example of where customer security is more important than User Experience or Owner business plan. Buy the upgraded version of the module or get the developer to refresh it so it works.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, would I guess you would recommand to run the highest PHP version.